# What does this array code mean?

Tags: php, arrays

I just inherited some code, and have not seen this format before. Here's an array:

```
$arrayWeather = array('weatherParameters' => array(
                                                   'wspd'  => $_GET['wspd']  == 'wspd',
                                                   'wdir'  => $_GET['wdir']  == 'wdir',
                                                   'waveh' => $_GET['waveh'] == 'waveh'));
```

I've never seen this before; what exactly does this mean?

```
'wspd'  => $_GET['wspd']  == 'wspd'
```

Is it a shortcut if statement, saying if _$GET['wspd'] exists, set the array key called wspd to the literal value wspd? Or something else entirely?

Comment: http://php.net/expressions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_GET['wspd']  == 'wspd'` is a boolean, and the value of that boolean is assigned to the `wspd` key in the subarray.

SO if `$_GET['wspd']` is "wspd", it will be the same as

```
 $arrayWeather = array('weatherParameters' => array(
                                               'wspd'  => true,
                                                etc...
```

Comment: Thank you. I've never seen that particular shorthand before.

Comment: Well, compare it to anyplace where you would normally have a boolean, like an `if`: `if($_GET['wspd'] == 'wspd')` would look a lot more familliar, wouldn't it? Now that comparison results in a boolean, which you can save somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

It gives the key called `'wspd'` the result of the equation `$_GET['wspd']  == 'wspd'`, which is either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

I know the 'wspd' => $_GET['wspd'] just sets the value of the 'wspd' key in the array now the second part i've never seen.

Answer (score 1):

Well... it's quite simple. You just assign the result of expression `$_GET['wspd']  == 'wspd'` (a boolean `true` or `false`) to the `wspd` index of `$arrayWeather`.